# Yii: Access Model Constant in Controller

Tags: php, yii

Using Yii Framework, how can I access Model Constant in Controller?

Model.php

```
...
const STATUS_ACTIVE=1;
...
```

Controller.php

```
...
$criteria->condition = 'status='.self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
...
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'STATUS_ACTIVE' in ... on line X
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your controller self is the controller's class who does not have this constant. I think you wanted:

```
Model::STATUS_ACTIVE
```

Where Model is the name of the model's class.
ie:

```
$criteria->condition = 'status='.Model::STATUS_ACTIVE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you Model Class object is $model, it will be

```
$criteria->condition = 'status=' . $model::STATUS_ACTIVE;
```

Unsure how the chosen answer works - certainly did not work for me.